# Rails Devise Routes: If user signed in, point to index. Else, point to new user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, devise, routes

Pretty simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer with a good ole fashioned Google.

**The error:**

```
undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc6369320e8> (NoMethodError)
```

**Server won't even start.**

**My code:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'u'
resources :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get 'user/edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :change_password
  end

  resources :apps do
    resources :elements, controller: 'apps/elements'
  end

  resources :elements do
      resources :features, except: [:index], controller: 'apps/elements/features'
  end

if user_signed_in?
  root to: 'apps#index'
else
devise_scope :user do
  root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
end

end
```

What's the best way to go about making this work? I'm hesitant to try to work around it and make the site vulnerable, being a new RoR user. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why aren't you redirecting the users within your controller action and not your routes

Comment: That's a good point. I just thought routes was the simplest way to do it. How should I redirect them to the devise new session page? So far I have `if user_signed_in? <the code for the user being signed in> else redirect_to <I don't know what to put here>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails access control is done on the controller layer - not on the routing layer.

Routes just define matchers for different sets of params and request urls. They are processed before rails even starts processing the request, they don't know anything about the session. Rails could have even used YML to define routes, except that Ruby is better at DSLs.

If you want to require that the user is signed in you would use:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! # a Devise helper method
end
```

Comment: Oh dear lord. You know what, I was using `:authenticate_user!` in my before filter but I put `except: :index` while I was working on devise features. I can't believe I just forgot to take it off and was about to do all sorts of dumb stuff. Thanks for clearing it up! Now time for some more coffee before I make another stupid move.

Comment: I would say your answer is useful, but I'm one rep point away from being able to. So in lieu of that, thank you to both of you!

Comment: So you had to set up the `before_action` callback in you `AppsController`?

Comment: You would only add `before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller? ` to ApplicationController if you want to lock down your entire app @Cyzanfar. More commonly auth is done on a per controller basis. Also note the `unless: :devise_controller?` which is needed so that your users can actually access the sign in page.